# DatGridView Row - Create and Format

Tags: c#, datagridview, formatting

I'm dynamically creating datagridview rows but cannot figure out exactly how to set the the colour and read-only status of a cell in that row unless i specifically loop over the entire datagridview after it's created.

What i want to do is something like the following (not valid code):

```
DataGridViewRow cata = catView.Rows.Add(new Object[] { item.catName,false, mLocalVersion, mServerVersion });

cata.Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: hmm...are you sure you need to do that at cell level? What about `datagridview.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;` ?

Comment: Yes, it's per cell that i might need to set readonly, not per column. I can acheive that after by looping over all the rows but i want to do it when the row is created.

Comment: See if my answer does what you want

Comment: Are you saying *some* `cells[1]` will be RO and others not?

Comment: Plutonix, yes. Pikoh, I'll give it a go, thanks.

Comment: When more than one person comment on your post, and you want one of them to get pinged, use `@`+username...there will be a popup to help complete the name

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your way of adding rows to your `DataGridView`is correct. Try this code and see if it does what you want:

```
DataGridViewRow cata = new DataGridViewRow();
cata.SetValues("item.catName", false, "mLocalVersion", "mServerVersion");
cata.Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
catView.Rows.Add(cata);
```

Comment: Hi Pikoh, I'm not setting read only for the entire row, just the one cell per row.

Comment: You are right. Try `cata.Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;`

Answer (score 0):

`some cells[1] will be RO and others not`

You can use the `RowsAdded` event.  This will be called when each row is added and allow you to evaluate other cells if needed.

```
private void dgv2_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "B")
    {
        dgv2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

If the thing which determines that a cell is RO changes (it could be the value of another cell), you should also change the RO property when the change is validated and saved.